# Extract partial strings from a ListBox that replace the text of the same ListBox

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, substring

I need help with my code.
I have a ListBox which contains lines of text like this:

```
"hello my friends, how r u?","today is good","hey"
"I'm fine","and you","doing"
"have a nice day","thanks","man"
```

I want to remove sub-strings using `SubString()` (or another method, it doesn't matter) for this ListBox items.
I want to see this output in my ListBox (same ListBox, not a new) when I compile my code.

```
hello my friends, how r u?
I'm fine
have a nice day
```

Note: I wanted to share my code but I couldn't produce any, sorry.

Comment: I'm really trying to understand what you want to do, can you maybe elaborate a bit more and just try to post some code. Do you want to iterate through the ListBox?

Comment: The `SubString()` method doesn't do what I think you think it does. It takes a string, e.g "Hello World" and makes a separate string out of it with 2 indexes. So `"Hello World".SubString(0, 3);` would return the characters from index 0 up to but excluding index 3, in this case "Hel". See more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: I have a listbox and it has items like this:

          "hello my friends, how r u?","today is good","hey"
          "I'm fine","and you","doing"
          "have a nice day","thanks","man"

But I want to see this output in my listbox when I compile to code:

          hello my friends, how r u?
          I'm fine
          have a nice day

I want to obtain between to first and second quotes for each line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate the ListBox `Items` collection, split the resulting strings and take just the first element, trimming the now useless quotes in the end.

```
for (int item = 0; item < listBox1.Items.Count; item++)
{
    listBox1.Items[item] = listBox1.Items[item].ToString()
            .Split(new[] { "\",\"" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[0].TrimStart('"');
}
```

Or something like this:

```
int i = -1;
listBox1.Items.OfType<string>().ToList().ForEach((s) => {
    listBox1.Items[++i] = s.Split(new[] { "\",\"" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[0].TrimStart('"');
});
```